# Are my nested for loops slow?

Tags: php, codeigniter, optimization

I'm currently working on an approval system right now using **PHP (Codeigniter)** and I have this method of getting all the request according to your department group and position depth.

The checking of the requests is based upon the user's position depth. 6 being the lowest and 1 being the highest. So basically there will be a maximum of 5 people to check the request. For example my depth is 6, line1 will be 5, line2 will be 4 and so on. The system will find someone with position depths like that and same department group. Lines 3 and 2 will decide to send it to ceo (1) or not so the default is only until 2.

**Some of my database columns**
[image: Some database columns]

It is designed that people above the line can check the request even if the lower lines havent checked it yet like for example maybe line1 havent checked it yet because he/she is on vacation and line3 cannot wait already so he/she decides to process the request because it is important. **Now if the above line processes it already, lower lines cannot process it anymore so they will only be allowed to view it.**

Now here comes my code of nested `for` loops in checking out all these things that I said. People say nested `for` loops, especially as many as mine is not a good practice. **Is my `for` loop gonna have problems when it comes to large data? If so how do I alter my code without altering my database for this?**

**This is my Model**

```
public function getRequestsToProcess($i,$depth,$departmentGroup)
{
    $this->db->select('*, ns_request_info.idx as request_idx, ns_staff_info.idx as staff_idx');    
    $this->db->from('ns_request_info');
    $this->db->join('ns_staff_info', 'ns_request_info.requested_by_idx = ns_staff_info.member_idx');
    $this->db->where('line'.$i.'', $depth);
    $this->db->where('line'.$i.'_action', 'PENDING');
    if($departmentGroup!='HIGHER TIER'){ $this->db->where('ns_staff_info.department_group', $departmentGroup); }
    $this->db->where('status', 'PENDING');
    $this->db->or_where('status', 'ONGOING');
    $this->db->where('line'.$i.'', $depth);
    $this->db->where('line'.$i.'_action', 'PENDING');
    if($departmentGroup!='HIGHER TIER'){ $this->db->where('ns_staff_info.department_group', $departmentGroup); }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**This is my method with nested `for` loops**

```
public function process()
{
    $data = new stdClass;
    $data->param_menu = 'request';

    $staffInfo = $this->staffinfo_model->selectItem(array('member_idx'=>$this->session->userdata('member_index')));

    for ( $i=1 ; $i<=5 ; $i++) {
        /*get lines with user depth and if same department group*/
        ${"line" . $i} = $this->staffrequisition_model->getRequestsToProcess($i,$staffInfo->position_depth,$staffInfo->department_group);

        for ($x = 0 ; $x < count(${"line" . $i}) ; $x++) {
            $counter = 0;
            for ($y = $i + 1 ; $y <=5 ; $y++) {
                if (${"line" . $i}[$x]['line'.$y.'_action']!=='PENDING' && ${"line" . $i}[$x]['line'.$y.'_action']!=='') {
                    $counter++;
                    break; 
                } 
            }
            if ($counter > 0) {
                ${"line" . $i}[$x]['is_checked'] = 1;
            } else {
                ${"line" . $i}[$x]['is_checked'] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    $data->param_requests = array_merge($line1, $line2, $line3, $line4, $line5);

    $this->load->view('dashboard/staff/process_view', $data);
}
```

Now `is_checked` being the marker if the request is already checked in upper lines. I hope you guys can give me any tips on how to optimize my code.

Comment: So ns_design_info is a giant denormalized table full of repeating groups?  Your database model is bizarre. You are using full strings 'APPROVED' 'PENDING' when you could instead have a table called status, with an unsigned tinyint as the foreign key.    This may be blunt, but for loops are the least of your problems.  This looks like a really inept design for an "approval" system, whatever that means, and the fact that you have all that convoluted code where you are trying to compute field names should tell you something.

Comment: @gview what do you mean by ns_design_info? There is no ns_design_info in my code? What do you suggest about my problem? Are you suggesting that I need to change my database for this?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant 'ns_request_info', and yes I am telling you that the design of that table is bad leading you into odd queries and odd code you would not need if the table(s) were properly normalized.

Comment: You posted this same question the day before and twice more on code review. Asking many times isn't going to get you an answer any faster and it just degrades the quality of the site. Your question really sounds like one that only you can address as only you have all the details. Chances are if you think its too slow or otherwise convoluted that's your intuition telling you it is.

Comment: First determine (via a few uses of `microtime()`) whether the loop is the slow part or the SQL is the slow part.  If it is the SQL, let's see the generated SQL.  Also `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables; there may be a simple database optimization.